# How do I add this autoplay script in Turn.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where do I put this code in Turn.Js?

```
setInterval(function() {
 $('#flipbook').turn('next');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: you can add it anywhere in your html page under <script> tag

Comment: generally script tags should go right above the closing `</body>` tag, but can be put higher up as long as it's below jQuery and whatever polugins it uses..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to wait for the page to finish loading, then execute this code. For this we use events.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#flipbook').turn('next');
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

The above code means that all the resources on the page have been loaded and rendered which seems appropriate since you will be hiding content upon triggering this code. Place this above the closing body tag `</body>` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just put this code just above </body>. But its not working. 

Here is my project documentation  

http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Tutorials

Comment: Create a jsFiddle and we can debug it.